# Download to root and after delete files from database

Tags: php, database, download

I have this function, and this deletes textfiles after a certain age from my database automatically.

```
$r = new textfiles;
$db = new DB;
$currTime_ori = $db->queryOneRow("SELECT NOW() as now");

...

if($this->site->textfilesretentiondays != 0)
        {
            echo "PostPrc : Deleting textfiles older than ".$this->site->textfilesretentiondays." days\n";

            $result = $db->query(sprintf("select ID from textfiles where postdate < %s - interval %d day", $db->escapeString($currTime_ori["now"]), $this->site->textfilesretentiondays));      
            foreach ($result as $row)
                $r->delete($row["ID"]);
        }
```

Now I would edit this function so that at first all textfiles are automatically downloaded in a root directory `/www/backup` and then the script should delete the textfiles with the string `$r->delete($row["ID"]);`

At the moment I have no idea how I could implement this.

Comment: What is textfiles class? Can you select the path of the files from your db?

Comment: All this runs over several .phps. Some have access to the database and the snippet above then processed further.

Comment: That's not a root directory, and without knowing how your filesystem maps to the URLs we don't know what the paths are. If the files are already on the server, what do you mean by "download"? Why are you using an expensive database query to determine the time? Why are you re-using that value as a parameter in the subsequent query instead of just using `now()`? This is a very confused question.

Comment: If your `delete()` method works as expected, then why not just create a `backup()` method that does something similar with the file, but using PHP's `copy()` function to back it up prior to delete?

Comment: are you sure that you need copy & delete ? .. maybe move can be used? and your sql-query `select ID from textfiles where postdate < %s - interval %d day` can be modified like this `select ID from textfiles where postdate < NOW() - interval %d day`.

Answer (score 3):

For me it's seems to be impossible to give you an completely answer to your question because leak of informations.

Do you store the whole file-content in database or only the path and filename?
It would help us to see whats the content of "`$row`" which represents one row from database.

---

If you just store the filename (and optionally the path) you could use the "copy" (http://php.net/manual/de/function.copy.php) function from php to copy the file to your backup-directory. Please note, you have to ensure that the user who's executing the script or running the web-server have the privileges to write into the directory.

You could add this functionality to class `textfiles` as as method like `makeBackup`.

Answer (score 1):

There are few information, but I'll give it a try. If you want to backup the rows before deleting them, you can store them in .txt file in json_encoded form using this piece of code inserted in the FOREACH loop, before delete command:

```
$myfile = fopen("/www/backup/".$row["ID"].".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = json_encode($row);
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Thx @ all for help ! Have now messing around with the proposals and the contribution from Aamir was the most helpful for me and give him the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

By your approach ..

```
function delete ($id){
   $result = $db->query(sprintf("select * from textfiles where id=$id);

   //if you have filepath use copy as SebTM suggested
   $path = $row['path']; //assuming path is the column name in ur db
   $filename = basename($path); //to get filename
   $backup_location = '/www/backup/'.$filename;
   copy($path, $backup_location);

   //if you have data in db
   $content = $row['data'] //assuming data to be backed up to file is in a field 'data'
   $backup_location = '/www/backup/file.txt';
   file_put_contents($backup_location, $content);
}
```

But this is not the most optimal approach , you could shift even the initial query into delete function above , and call delete function only once, instead of calling it in a loop ..